# In the context of lenet, does C1 refer to the conv layer or the output of the conv layer?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, terminology

I'm studying lenet.

## C1 is the layer

According to a tutorial, C1 is

> the first convolutional layer with 6 convolution kernels of size 5× 5.

[image]

## C1 is the feature map

However, I believe that the part pointed out by the red arrow in the following image represents the first convolutional layer, while C1 refers to the feature maps, which are the output of that layer. Is my understanding correct?

[image]